# is this a part interrupt?

Tags: theory, harmony, voice-leading

at measure 6 ,
the soprano starts with the G
so shouldn't the alto not go over the G
till the next measure ?
but you could see the alto is getting higher then the G through the measure..
is this a part interrupt ?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're discussing what is commonly called a **voice overlap**. A voice overlap occurs when, from one chord to the next, a voice moves into the register of a neighboring voice. In the example below, a voice overlap occurs on beat 4 because the bass is higher than the tenor was in the previous chord.

[image]

Your example would be a voice overlap if the chords moved immediately from beat 1 to beat 3. However, since your example has beat 2 between those two chords, it is no longer a voice overlap. Voice overlap occurs over the span of *two* chords. Since your example occurs over the span of *three* chords, it is acceptable.

---

Voice overlap is not to be confused with a **voice crossing**, which is when voices move into the register of a neighboring voice *in the same chord*. In the example below, a voice crossing occurs on beat 4 when the soprano line (the stemmed-up E) moves below the alto (the stemmed-down A).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you've written is fine.  All parts have a singable line.   Voice overlaps and crossings should be used with caution, but I don't consider them to be prohibited.